# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'customId' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

If I run the following component, I get this error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'customId' of undefined**

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { db } from '../firebase';

const DocList = ({ card }) => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [customId, setCustomId] = useState(card.customId);
  const [originalText, setOriginalText] = useState(card.originalText);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      const data = db.collection('FlashCards').orderBy('customId').get();
      setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
      <ul className='list'>
        {cards.map((card) => (
          <li key={card.id} className='list__item' data-id={card.id}>
            <input
              type='text'
              value={customId}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setCustomId(Number(e.target.value));
              }}
            />
            <div className='list__textarea-wrapper'>
              <textarea
                value={originalText}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setOriginalText(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  );
};

export default DocList;
```

Comment: You're probably passing `undefined` as the `card` prop to `DocList`.

Comment: Can you please add <DocList code piece as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can't reach the customerId of card object.

```
const [customId, setCustomId] = useState(card?.customId);
const [originalText, setOriginalText] = useState(card?.originalText);
```

Can you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

On the very first render this won't work:

```
const DocList = ({ card }) => {
...
```

You are trying to destructure `card` from `props` object, which apparently doesn't come from the parent component. Check up to the tree where you're rendering the `<DocList />`

Answer (score -1):

During component initlization,

```
const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
```

`cards` is an array which don't have `customId` property.

```
const [customId, setCustomId] = useState(card.customId);// so,this will give an error.
```

in below code,`setCards` set set to an array of object and not to object

```
setCards(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
```

Comment: it is cards array and other one is card object as a prop, they are not same.